# Casting comma separated to integer for IN clause

Tags: sqlite

I have three tables estimate, location and department. Now I am JOINing tables location and estimate to get desired results.

**Query**

```
SELECT e.id, e.department_ids FROM estimate e JOIN location l ON e.location_id = l.id  WHERE  e.user_id = '1' and e.delete_flag = 0 and l.active_flag = 1
```

**Result**

[image]

For above requirement this query was working fine.

Now I want relevant department names as well. So I am using this query

**Query**

```
SELECT e.id, e.department_ids, (SELECT group_concat(department, ', ') FROM department WHERE id IN (e.department_ids)) as departmentName FROM estimate e JOIN location l ON e.location_id = l.id  WHERE  e.user_id = '1' and e.delete_flag = 0 and l.active_flag = 1
```

**Result**

[image]

which gives me only departments with single department id.

Although if I hardcode e.department as "2, 5" I am getting desired result

**Query**

```
SELECT e.id, e.department_ids, (SELECT group_concat(department, ', ') FROM department WHERE id IN (2, 5)) as departmentName FROM estimate e JOIN location l ON e.location_id = l.id  WHERE  e.user_id = '1' and e.delete_flag = 0 and l.active_flag = 1
```

**Result**

[image]

I tried cast(e.department_ids as integer), but this is also taking single department_id per row. Is there any function I can cast whole string of e.departments (i.e. "4, 2") so that I can pass that in IN clause?

I got solution for the same in oracle, I could find it's equivalent for sqlite.

Comment: Storing a comma-separated list in the database is horrible design. Can't you change that?

Comment: @CL. I can't change it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the desired result using `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Can you share that query?

Comment: @Baby Groot Please can i have that query for sqllite?